# Azue Linux machine not connecting

Tags: linux, azure, ssh

While working on a Microsoft Azure virtual machine I noticed it was lagging significantly, so I decided to run the sudo reboot command then ssh back in. When I tried to ssh back in with

```
ssh user@ipaddress
```

i got the error:

```
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out.
```

When I run the ssh command using -vvv i get:

```
OpenSSH_6.9p1, LibreSSL 2.1.8
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 53: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to xxx.xx.xx.xxx [xxx.xx.xx.xxx] port 22.
debug1: connect to address xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
ssh: connect to host xxx.xx.xx.xxx port 22: Operation timed out
```

Comment: What happens when you ping that ip? Do you manage that host? Does it have a firewall? Is an Ssh server running?

Comment: This error can mean that the machine did not come back up.

Comment: When I ping the ip it returns: `PING xxx.xx.xx.xxx (xxx.xx.xx.xxx): 56 data bytes
Request timeout for icmp_seq 0
Request timeout for icmp_seq 1
Request timeout for icmp_seq 2
Request timeout for icmp_seq 3
Request timeout for icmp_seq 4
Request timeout for icmp_seq 5
Request timeout for icmp_seq 6
Request timeout for icmp_seq 7
Request timeout for icmp_seq 8...` and it keeps on going on like that

Comment: Well if you can't ping it, you definitely can't ssh. Try rebooting again. Is it possible ssh or your firewall is started at boot and you're locked out? Are you on the same private network?

Comment: Is there a different reboot command I can use that ensures the machine starts back up correctly? How do I know if I'm locked out?

Comment: You cannot ping from outside of Azure - ICMP does not go through. Did your IP address change? (check in the portal - typically a reboot is going to get you a new IP address unless you have a static IP address).

Answer (score 1):

If you did a shutdown, IP of machine has been changed. Check it in the control panel.